# excel formula, sum by month error

Tags: excel

`=SUMIFS(amount, folioidd, folioid, MONTH(auditdate), 1)`

`=SUMPRODUCT(amount*folioidd=folioid*[MONTH(auditdate)=1])`
**i guess there is some syntax error with [MONTH(auditdate)=1]**

I tried both, but they dont work, how to correct it? the error message is in chinese, therefore i didn't put it up here

**this is the data:**

amount      folioid         auditdate

120            123            5/1/2018

126            456            7/1/2018

560            123            25/1/2018

**the resulting table i want:**

folioidd    Jan    Feb    Mar

123        680

456        126

Comment: Are those the exact formulas in your cells? Are you working with named ranges? If not, please post your formulas with the cell references.

Comment: i have edited the formula, it should be exact

Comment: Are you using words (eg. "folioidd") in your formula because of named ranges, or because your data is in a table?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

first of your create on column "Month" 
month formula : =MONTH(C2)

then after try this =SUMIFS(A2:A6,B2:B6,A10,D2:D6,1)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get resulting table using pivot table in excel.

You need to change date formating to mm/dd/yyyy and then you can get sum by grouping column auditdate based on month.

[image]

Date changed to mm/dd/yyyy format

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can i not pick the exact date? say 1/5/18-31/5/18,  because i also have data from 2017, 2016......  and can i do it with only formula?

Comment: I don't think you can because when I tried I was getting May-01, July-01 dates. But you can try changing the format for the cells.
You have result as a table, so the result in a table format can only be achieved using a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

For the data below, I used the formula:

```
ID  Amount  Date
123 10  28-Jan
789 20  29-Jan
789 30  30-Jan
123 40  31-Jan
789 50  1-Feb
789 60  2-Feb
123 70  3-Feb
789 80  4-Feb
123 90  5-Feb
123 100 6-Feb

SUMIFS(Amount, ID, RefID, Date, ">="&RefDt1, Date, "<=" & RefDt2)
```

where RefID is your reference ID cell, and RefDt1 is your lower end of reference date (like 01-01-2018) and and RefDt2 is your higher end of reference date (like 31-01-2018)